# HttpClient request in C# windows App

Tags: c#, windows, networking

In Windows App HttpClient is used to send request to get any response.Internally is this request goes as UDP or TCP or some other way ?

Comment: The default is TCP. While HTTP *could* be used over UDP that is very rare. Are you trying to use a different protocol?

Comment: can we change it. ? and use UDP

Comment: Why? Does your server support it? You won't be able to use UDP if the server *doesn't* support HTTP over UDP. Given how rare this is (I had to look to Wikipedia for such cases) I doubt you can find a non-experimental server that works this way

Comment: Are you trying to use CoAP?